# How should I respond to a moderator's comment on a deleted answer?

Tags: support, comment, deleted-answers

[Arthur Fischer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8348/arthur-fischer) commented on [one of my deleted answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1058866/184794) asking why it was deleted. I do not know how he expects me to answer, since I seem unable to comment on it and I do not know of a way to PM other users. So, how should I respond to a comment on a deleted answer?

I may as well answer him here now that I am making this question: The OP noticed and fixed an error in their question, which made my answer irrelevant.

Comment: I think you can flag your answer for moderator attention and respond there.

Comment: You deleted the answer, I think you can undelete it and then comment (and then redelete it, if you like).

Comment: @GerryMyerson That's what I was thinking, but it seemed a bit too hacky to be the preferred solution. In addition, I was not sure if it would have sent a notification to the OP, which would have been undesirable as the answer definitely deserved deletion.

Comment: It was pointed out to the moderators that the question was quite closely related to a KöMaL competition problem that closed yesterday, and was wondering if _that_ was the reason you deleted your answer. My comment should have been more descriptive, for which I apologise. (I'm perhaps too used to being able to comment everywhere. `#modworldproblems`)

Comment: @Arthur: Does a flag (on the comment, perhaps) make a reasonable method to reply without undeleting/redeleting? What about comments on deleted posts, do you still get pinged anyway? `#hashtags`

Comment: @Asaf: Flags might not be the _best_ way to communicate with mods, but that _is_ a possibility. `@`-replies do not work in comments on deleted posts (only the author of the post is notified). And I probably shouldn't have left a comment anyway, since the OP shouldn't have been notified. ([source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96343/214632)) `#s-might-exist`

Comment: @Arthur: Thanks `#useless-comment #useless-hashtag`

Comment: @Arthur: Thanks for responding. It might be good if you left an answer here.

Comment: Actually, @regret: _did_ you receive a notification of my comment on that deleted post?

Comment: @Arthur: I did receive a notification for it, yes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In actual fact, this is *entirely* my fault. A user had flagged the question indicating that it was quite closely related to a problem in a KöMaL competition that ended yesterday. When I first saw it, the question and the answer were deleted, and I just let it stand. This (my-)morning I undeleted the question since it seemed to have received an answer and appeared to be another see-answer-and-run situation, and was then curious why you had deleted your answer.

What I *should* have written is something along these lines:

> The question above is closely related to a problem in a KöMaL competition. If *this* is the reason you decided to delete your answer, I just want to let you know that the competition has now finished, so feel free to undelete it.

(I also *should* have had more coffee this morning; working on that presently.)

---

In general there is no good way to respond to moderator comments on deleted posts. That regular users cannot comment on deleted posts is certainly [status-by-design](/questions/tagged/status-by-design). Raising flags in these instances is not really appropriate (though I guess could work in a pinch). You *could* comment on some other undeleted post of my own (again, slight misuse and I don't want to receive a ton of notifications in this manner, but as a mod I can clear out the off-topic stuff rather quickly). I'm personally an infrequent guest in the main chatroom (though other mods are fairly active, and they can reach me fairly easily if I'm available; maybe I should try to ensure that I'm at least pingable from the main room by popping my <s>head</s> avatar in there every couple days).

Again, my comment was unclear and therefore bad, and I apologise for any confusion.

Comment: No problem, thank you for clearing things up.

Comment: If you don't mind explaining, what is a "see-answer-and-run situation"?

Comment: @regret: (1) Ask question (usually applies to those from a homework assignment, exam or contest), (2) receive answer, (3) delete question before the answer receives any upvotes to "hide" evidence.

Answer (score 3):

In principle, you could undelete, leave a comment, and delete again. But this is somewhat awkward, and it is not even obvious whether the ping will reach the target user under such circumstances.

A better way to reply would be in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics). You don't need to wait for the other party to be there; ping will work as long as the @-mention of the name auto-completes (meaning the user was in the room not too long ago).

Or perhaps you don't need to reply at all.